# failed network error when downloading images in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, object, download

When I try to download image on button click in javascript, am getting `failed network error`

```
function downloadImg(url, name){
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = `data:application/octet-stream;base64,${encodeURIComponent(url)}`;
    link.download = name;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);

}

<button onclick=this.downloadImg("http://www.example.com/image.png", "img1.png");>Download</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use this code

```js
const downloadImg = document.getElementById('downImg')

downloadImg.onclick = function() {
  const url = downloadImg.getAttribute('imgurl')
  const name = downloadImg.getAttribute('name')
  const link = document.createElement('a');

  link.href = `data:application/octet-stream;base64,${encodeURIComponent(url)}`;
  link.download = name;
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

```html
 <button id="downImg" imgurl="https://thesafety.us/images/articles/javascript-logo.png" name="javascript-logo.png">Download</button>
```

Comment: I don`t get error in my code, check you for same names in url and name "http://www.example.com/IMAGE.png", "IMAGE.png" and existing file in url